# Trimming numeric field to only show multiples of 0.00 [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to be able to retrieve all rows where the `trans_amount` field ends is in multiples of 0.00. The `trans_amount` field is `Numeric`

BEFORE

`select trans_amount from transactions`

```
|trans_amt|
+--------+
|-4513.19|
|-200.00 | 
|-2346.13|
|3140.00 |
```

AFTER:

```
|trans_amt|
+--------+
|-200.00 | 
|3140.00 |
```

What regular expression operator can achieve this?

Comment: floor(val) <> val ? (or round)

Comment: regular expressions are for strings.  What is the datatype of the trans_amt field?

Comment: Any multiple of 0.00 will be 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all i am not in postgres and if you are looking for regular expression then this is not the answer but this answer will work for you surely

since you are looking for multiples of 0.00 which essentially means you are looking for multiples of 10 and can be achieved by follwoing

```
trans_amt % 10 = 0
```

**EDIT**

this should work in [postgresql] too

please see **[this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/23189/2)** for demo

```
Select * from tab1 where trans_amt % 10 = 0
```

Comment: Yes I'm looking for multiples of 10. But that doesn't work in postgresql, sadly

Comment: According to this it should.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-math.html

Comment: This did work and I believe it is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.